# Implementation details of fmt.Println in golang

Tags: go, floating-accuracy

Consider this code

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "math/big"
)

func main() {
    var b1,b2,b3,bigSum big.Float

    b1.SetFloat64(25.3)
    b2.SetFloat64(76.2)
    b1.SetFloat64(53.1)

    bigSum.Add(&b1, &b2).Add(&b3, &bigSum)

    fmt.Println(bigSum)   // {53 0 0 1 false [9317046909104082944] 8}
    fmt.Println(&bigSum)  // 129.3
 }
```

I have 2 questions

1. Why I have to pass `bigSum` as **reference** (by using `&`) to get the correct answer, otherwise we'll get back an object?
2. How does `Println` work in Go? I mean how does it know which format it should apply for different types?

Comment: re 2 - it uses reflection. checkout the `reflect` package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `Println` determines whether the value implements the `Stringer` interface. If it does then it will call the `String()` to get formatted value. `big.Float` implements it for pointer receiver so you have to pass a reference. Otherwise `Println` will detect that it's a struct and print all of it's fields using reflection
2. Go is open sourced. You can see for yourself https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?#L738 It uses type switches and reflection.